# how to convert or display emf image in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, image

this is a part of the documentation for a device I'm working on.
any idea how to interpret this to an image or bitmap or anything usable?

this definition below is xml definitions

3.2.13. IMAGE

properties: content complex

children: IMAGE_DATA

used by: complexType Cbc_Result

attributes: Name Type Use Default Fixed Annotation

ImageType Type_Image required

DataSize xs:long required

This node gathers information on an images files calculated by the software(Image_Data represents entire content of an emf file representing an image)

sample data :

> < IMAGE DataSize="6676" ImageType="3">< IMAGE_DATA>AQAAAGwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMcAAABjAAAAA
>   AAAAAAAAABNEgAANQwAACBFTUYAAAEAFBoAAI0AAAAF
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVgUAAAADAABAAQAA8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADiBACAqQMAEQAAAAwA
>   AAAIAAAAEgAAAAwAAAACAAAAFAAAAAwAAAANAAAACQAAABAAAADIMgAAjBwAAAkAAAAQAAAAyDIA
>   AIwcAAALAAAAEAAAAMgAAABkAAAASwAAAEAAAAAwAAAABQAAACAAAAABAAAAAQAAABAAAAAAAAAA
>   AAAAADB1AAAwdQAAAA< /IMAGE_DATA>< /IMAGE>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Base64 encoded (with stripped == signes at the end) content of file in EMF format - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile.

Make sure to add needed number of = at the end (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 for details) to successfully use Conver.FromBase64 function to get byte array.

I don't know if regular rendering methods support EMF... But Check Drawing namespace and Image class in particular.